# Overstaying in the US, is it possible to go to Guam and get back to LA?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, overstaying, guam

A friend has been overstaying in the US for 8 months, he has a valid tourist visa. Will he be able to go to Guam and get back to LA? Do you have to go through customs and immigration? Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason he’s hellbent on returning to (or staying in) the US on an expired visa?  Seems like a bad idea, especially under our current... regime.  If it were me, I’d be more interested in getting out/back home, ideally without my overstay being detected.

Answer (score 54):

He will most likely be able to make it to Guam - there are generally no passport checks, although legally he is still required to carry his passport.

However once he is in Guam, he's in for a world of pain.

Non-US citizens do require a passport to depart Guam, and he WILL be processed by CBP before departing Guam back to the US mainland.  At that point his overstay in the US will be detected, and he will very likely be detained for deportation.

Note that despite your comment, he does NOT have a "valid" tourist visa.  Once he overstayed any period of time (and especially after overstaying more than 180 days) his visa is no longer valid.  Having overstayed more than 180 days, he will also be subject to a minimum 3 year ban when he does leave the country - or likely more if he is deported.

(There are a small number of exceptions to the above, such as if the person is below 18 years old)

Comment: Automatically Void Visa: If you overstay the end date of your authorized stay, as provided by the CBP officer at a port-of-entry, or United States Citizenship and Immigration Services (USCIS), your visa will [automatically void or cancel](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-expiration-date.html) unless;

You have filed an application in a timely manner for an extension of stay or a change of status;
That application is pending and not frivolous;

Comment: @MusoniusRufus - Hmmm, those applications according to their website can be expected to take up to 4.5 months to process. It might be possible to submit one and at least buy himself some time. But probably the smartest thing to do would be to go talk to an experienced immigration lawyer immediately.

Comment: @T.E.D. "It might be possible to submit one and at least buy himself some time." - No. His visa is already invalid. His application wouldn't be filled "in a timely manner". By filling it now he would pretty much just turn himself in for deportation.

Comment: @Mołot - Most likely yes. But it seems possible it might take them a while to bounce it back, and in the meantime he *would* have a pending extension app that has not yet been judged on its timelyness. Either way, it beats being arrested in Guam.

Comment: I understand that CBP requires non-US citizens to show passports to fly from Guam to another part of US territory, but as far as I can see there is no basis for this in law.  If OP's friend has a lot of money and a good lawyer, he might be able to challenge it in court, but if that were true he probably wouldn't be in this situation in the first place.

Comment: This issue came up yesterday in [Travel to Puerto Rico without a Passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/123727/19400).  I've asked a related question on [Law.SE]: [Passport requirements for travel between a US territory and a US state](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/32510/333).

Comment: @phoog: I believe that the reason they need to check people's status when flying from Guam to another part of the US is that there is a Guam-CNMI Visa Waiver Program, which is separate from, and allows some additional countries than, the regular US VWP. But the Guam-CNMI VWP does not allow the person to visit the rest of the US. So they need to check that the person is in a status that can go to the rest of the US.

Comment: @user102008 That makes sense, but what about Puerto Rico?  And, more to the point, what if someone has a visa but doesn't have their passport with them?  If there's no legal requirement to carry the passport, such a person should be allowed to fly without one, but CBP [says](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/980/~/needing-a-passport-to-enter-the-united-states-from-u.s.-territories) "upon departure, a passport is required for all but U.S. citizens"; as far as I can see there's no basis in law for that claim.

Comment: +1, but it's actually possible that they will enter a world of pain immediately on arrival in Guam: my understanding is that you'll go through U.S. immigration in Guam, *even if coming from Honolulu*, and your overstay will likely be spotted then and there.